# How to select the powershell command from Alias and Run that command

Tags: powershell

What i want to do is strip the output of the Alis command and get the power-shell command from it and run that command.

how i would do this in bash would be i would cut the input and get the second column then store each line in a list. then get the line that starts with the command i want and use a regular expression to get the seperateor "-> " and then put the result after that in a string and run that command. kinda like this

(if alias worked the same in bash that it does in powershell)

output of alias cd

```
CommandType    Name                  Version           Source
-----------    ----                  -------           ------ 
Alias          cd -> Set-Location
```

What i want to do is grab the Set location from the command and store that into a string to run the command latter. the fields is not tab delimited they are space delimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how i would do this in bash would be i would cut the input and get the second column then store each line in a list. then get the line that starts with the command i want and use a regular expression to get the seperateor "-> " and then put the result after that in a string

Fortunately for you, PowerShell cmdlets emit objects instead of text, so it's much easier to extract information like this.

To get the definition of an alias, select the `definition` property of the object output by `get-alias`:

```
get-alias cd |select-object -expandproperty definition
```

In short, **anytime** you start thinking "I'll parse the text output of this cmdlet" in PowerShell, you're probably doing it wrong. Instead, pipe the cmdlet to `Get-Member` and look at the properties and methods hanging off the output object(s). Then interrogate those. PowerShell is object-based, not text-based. If you've been living in bash for a few years/decades, it's an adjustment you **have** to make.

Comment: For running the aliased command you need to call the expanded property: `& (Get-Alias ...)`. However, I doubt that there are many aliases where this would actually be useful.

Comment: Thanks i didn't think to look at the object it spits out. I'm use to just using bash so going to power shell is a bit weird to me. I got it to work by just using the text but this way is much more elegant and easier to use.